# Flutter Path setup issue in mac

Tags: flutter-dependencies

I download flutter in my download folder. Then I follow the each step which required to setup the flutter path in mac. But my problem is that when I close terminal each time it need to setup the path. I mean the path is not permanently set up. My Question is that-
Is there any problem if I keep the flutter into the downloads directory?

Comment: there should not be an issue. can you share the link you are following to install?

Comment: If the problem is that you have to run something like `export Path="<something>:$PATH"`, then you can just add that line to your `~/.zshrc` file or equivalent if you use a different shell.

Answer (score 0):

[flutter setup guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos) literally says

> This command sets your PATH variable for the current terminal window only.

Did you follow also this [guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path) ?

Keeping flutter in downloads folder should not be problem. Better practise is to move it to USERNAME/Developer/flutter

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Yes, I follow the flutter setup guide. Initially it works but when I close my terminal and reopen it I have to run [ export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin" ] this command each time. Then I can access flutter otherwise it shows flutter command not found.

Comment: sure but the command you use (which contains the pwd) isn't enough. You need to follow the second link I posted and use this command and replace the path in square brackets with your path:  export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin"